# xclock not runnnig for another user

Tags: linux, solaris, oracle-vm-server

I have install new solaris 10 in Virtual box in my pc. I have set below command as a root user.

```
bash-3.2#export DISPLAY=":0.0" DISPLAY
bash-3.2#xclock
```

It is working fine for root user but I have another user named: mamun

I have run xclock for "mamun" but it shows below error message.

```
$xclock
Xlib: connection to ":0.0" refused by server
Xlib: No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: :0.0
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick way around this is by doing:

```
xhost +manun
```

but you probably should just logout (as root) and start the X session as "mamun" then you would not have these problems. And running X as root can have security problems and is generally frowned upon.

Comment: @mamun06 If this solves your problem, please consider accepting this answer by clicking the ✔ (checkmark) next to the answer. That is the way other people know your problem has been solved. If a better answer comes along, you can always change the accepted answer.